# How to show an Interstitial in MainActivity?

Tags: android, admob, interstitial

I would like that every time the user accesses the MainActivity an Interstitial appears, but I do not know how to proceed.
Thank You!!!

My code:

```
   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // FIREBASE INTERSTICIAL
        mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
        mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-2565065222479596/5036943452");

        mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdClosed() {

                requestNewInterstitial();
            }
        });

        requestNewInterstitial();


    // FIREBASE INTERSTICIAL
    private void requestNewInterstitial() {
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .addTestDevice("SEE_YOUR_LOGCAT_TO_GET_YOUR_DEVICE_ID")
                .build();

        mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you never called `.show()` on the interstitial.

According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/interstitial#show_the_ad):

> Interstitial ads should be displayed during natural pauses in the flow
>   of an app. Between levels of a game is a good example, or after the
>   user completes a task. To show an interstitial, use the isLoaded()
>   method to verify that it's done loading, then call show().

I wouldn't recommend showing it every time a user access an activity. **Note**: your code will load and show another interstitial *every time* one interstitial is done loading - creating a never ending loop of interstitials!

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // FIREBASE INTERSTITIAL
        mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
        mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-2565065222479596/5036943452");

        mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded() {
                // Code to be executed when an ad finishes loading.
                mInterstitialAd.show(); // add this line to show.
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdClosed() {
                // Code to be executed when the interstitial ad is closed.
                requestNewInterstitial(); // never-ending loop of ads, avoid!!
            }
        });

        requestNewInterstitial();
    }

    // FIREBASE INTERSTITIAL
    private void requestNewInterstitial() {
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .addTestDevice("SEE_YOUR_LOGCAT_TO_GET_YOUR_DEVICE_ID")
                .build();

        mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Learn about the Activity lifecycle: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle